# Replicate data from Lotus Notes to MSSql

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, lotus-notes, lotus

I have Lotus Notes application, and a lot of people insets data inside this application. 
For different reason I need those data also copied into MSSql database, for other programs to use it.

Right now, we use export data to excel and insert them to MSSql database, but this has some drawback. As first we export to excel daily, so data inside MSSql database are not current. And second is that is needed a man labour.

My task is to fix this. I could probably implement job that automatically create export and then import to MSSql, but I am looking if there is a way to replicate data between those two databases.

Has someone some experience in this? The best solution would be replication of the databases. Second best solution would be to catch trigger when data is stored in Note database. I read that Notes use Java. Do anyone know if you could catch trigger when data is stored into database.

I am using Lotus Notes 8.5

Comment: Maybe you don't need to replicate at all - it seems to be possible to create a Linked Server: [Linked Lotus Notes database to SQL Server 2012](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5c7eac73-16ce-4ec3-9667-61a69d99b928/linked-lotus-notes-database-to-sql-server-2012-i-need-to-query-the-data?forum=sqldataaccess) to make your Lotus Notes data accessible in SQL Server.

Comment: Hi, Filburt. Thank you for reply. I will try this, but from a first look, it seems to me that this is not something that I need. My problem is that I have two already implemented systems. One is Notes, and other use (already created) tables in SQL Server database. So ideally would be to copy data to same tables in database.

Comment: If you insist on copying the (changed) data, add [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services) to the mix and use the ootb [SDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/slowly-changing-dimension-transformation) (or a generated [MERGE statement](http://scdmergewizard.codeplex.com/) ) to extract the changed data. This will give you a highly reliable, automated process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to answer your last question. The rest is really too broad. There are many, many ways to synchronize data between a Notes/Domino database and MS SQL Server or just about any other database. There are a lot of 3rd-party products that can do this

But now I'll answer this: Second best solution would be to catch trigger when data is stored in Note database. I read that Notes use Java. **Do anyone know if you could catch trigger when data is stored into database.***

The answer is yes, you can catch a trigger. There is a set of Notes C API routines known as [Extension Manager](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/9.0/api90ug.nsf/85255d56004d2bfd85255b1800631684/06fd173414dcdad9852560eb0077ca42?OpenDocument) that is designed specifically for that. The C API is quite complex, requiring deep knowledge of Notes programming, and the EM routines add another layer of complexity. Fortunately, though, there's an open source project called [Trigger Happy](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Trigger%20Happy) on the OpenNTF site that gives you the code you need for an Extension Manager routine that can invoke a Java agent when it catches an [NSFNoteUpdate](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/9.0/api90ref.nsf/61fd4e9848264ad28525620b006ba8bd/85255d56004d3f6385255b4500731b93?OpenDocument) event.

Note, however, that Anyone with even modest experience with Notes would have already known that it supports Java, so I suspect you are very new to this. Trigger Happy makes this task a lot easier than writing your own Extension Manger routines, but it doesn't get you off the hook from having to learn quite a lot about Notes and Domino in order to do this job - including a lot of learning about how to use the Notes Java API and at least learning the basics about how Extension Manager works and about the events that it can capture.

Even with Trigger Happy, I would still recommend that you engage the services of someone who has done this sort of thing before. It's going to be capturing events on your server and running code on your server. If not done well, this could easily slow your server down (a lot!) or even crash it.

Comment: Thank you, for reply. Yes we are really really new to Note, but  we have huge knowledge of databases, replications, ... But .nsf database is now for us. I found out that there is a ODBC driver for it. I will try with this and with 3rd party product for replication first.  Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: IBM has their own product, called Enterprise Integrator. http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibmenterpriseintegrator Casahl has a product called ecKnowlege. https://www.casahl.com/dart-product-suite/ecknowledge/  Percussion has a product called Notrix. https://www.percussion.com/products/notrix/  There are others that I'm not remembering at the moment. If you enter 'lotus notes etl' into google, you'll find references to various products in the Extract/Transform/Load category that can probably help you, too.

Answer (score 1):

in our company we have a similar requirement ...

So what i do is drop the database table every day, create a new one and fill in the data of our employee directory.

I have written a notes agent which runs periodically every day. I use ADODB as COM-Object to access the database. Looping through the employees documents creates one "insert into ..." command for every employee.

Maybe these hints point to the right direction.

Greetz, Markus

Answer (score 0):

This is what DECS does... Two-way instantaneous synchronisation...